# RadAutoCompleteTextView with events not working

Tags: android, nativescript, angular2-nativescript

I am trying to trigger an event on city selected by the user in `RadAutoCompleteTextView` but is not working

`(tokenSelected)="onTokenSelected($event)"` // not working

`(tokenAdded)="onTokenAdded($event)"` // not working

`(textChanged)="onTextChanged($event)"` // working

Also I want to select a city by typing any of matching letters.

For example "Vatican City", user may type 'cit' or 'can' as "Vatican City" contains both, it should display.

[here](https://play.nativescript.org/?template=play-ng&id=wLWq73) is a playground for quick reference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your Playground Sample you have set `displayMode` to `Plain`. You could expect `tokenAdded` / `tokenSelected` events to work only when the `displayMode` is set to `Tokens`. `textChanged` event seems already working.

You may have to refer the [docs](https://docs.nativescript.org/ui/professional-ui-components/AutoCompleteTextView/autocomplete-display-modes) carefully and pay bit more attention to what you write.

Comment: OK, then what is the event when displayMode="Plain"

Comment: As I already mentioned, all you have to do is to refer the docs the information is already there. Use [didAutoComplete](https://docs.nativescript.org/ns-ui-api-reference/classes/radautocompletetextview#didautocompleteevent) event.